# Perl: Create a hash from an array

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures, hash

If I have the following array

```
my @header_line = ('id', 'name', 'age');
```

How do I create a hash from it equivalent to the line below?

```
my %fields = { id => 0, name => 1, age => 2};
```

The reason I want to do this is so that I can use meaningful names rather than magic numbers for indexes. For example:

```
$row->[$fields{age}]; # rather than $row->[2]
```

Comment: why not change `$row` to `%row` (a hash)?

Comment: It comes from Text::CSV e.g., my $row = $csv->getline($fh)

Comment: Since you have @header_line, you can turn $row to a hash quite easily: `my %row_hash = map { $_ => shift @{$row} } @header_line;`. Just another alternative, but might be cleaner using `$row_hash{age}` than having to use the `$row->[$fields{age}]` notation...

Comment: Since you have @header_line, you can turn $row to a hash quite easily: my %row_hash; @row_hash{@header_line} = @{$row};. I had to think a second about how your code worked, and a hash slice is much cleaner.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
my %fields;
@fields{@header_line} = (0 .. $#header_line);
```

Comment: @swisstony: It just came to my mind, if your indexes are known statically, constants would be more convenient. `use constant { id => 0, name => 1, age => 2}; print $row->[age];`

Comment: I see, but then I would have to maintain two data structures. I already have an array called header_line, which is used when printing column names ($csv->print( $fh, get_header_line();). I would also have to maintain a separate hash for the indexes. I should say I actually have about 40 column names in header_line not the 3 as in my example. I suppose it would work if I could create the header_line as a ref to an array from the hash, which is what Text::CSV wants, but I'm not sure how to that.

Answer (score 6):

```
my %fields = map { $header_line[$_] => $_ } 0..$#header_line;
```

Answer (score 3):

You said in reply to a comment that this is coming from Text::CSV.  This module has a way to import this into a hash for you.

`$csv->column_names( @header_line );

$row = $csv->getline_hr( $FH );

print $row->{ 'id' };`

Comment: Didn't know about column_names and getline_hr - they were added in 2008, so relatively recent (in terms of Text::CSV). Makes the code much tidier...

Comment: I nearly got this working. The problem is $csv_o->print( $fh_o, $row ); fails because it expects an array ref. How do I write out the hash ref using the csv_o object? BTW, my script reads in one CSV, adds some fields, changes all column names (@header_line is new col names), and then writes out a new CSV file. I hadn't appreciate what I needed may be right under my nose. **Very many thanks for your comment!**

Comment: I've raised this as a new question as quite different to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163048/perl-with-textcsv-can-i-write-out-a-hash-ref

Answer (score 1):

```
my %fields = ();
for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@header_line); $i++) {
   $fields{$header_line[$i]} = $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TIMTOWTDI

```
my %fields = ();
foreach my $field(@header_line)
{
  $fields{$field} = scalar(keys(%fields));
}
```